# Why is it bad to use inline styling in HTML for generic styles?

Tags: html, css

Given

```
<div>
   <textarea></textarea>
</div>
```

Why is this

```
<div>
   <textarea class="width90"></textarea>
</div>

.width90{
   width:90%;
}
```

any better than this?

```
<div>
   <textarea style="width:90%;"></textarea>
</div>
```

edit:
I updated my example better. My question should be more related to *generic styles* like widths, text align, etc.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When should I use a CSS class over inline styling?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/125893/when-should-i-use-a-css-class-over-inline-styling)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is it (or was it) important to separate CSS from HTML?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/271294/why-is-it-or-was-it-important-to-separate-css-from-html)

Comment: If your site has 50 "myTextArea" textareas scattered in different places and you need to change the width of all of them to 85%, you'll be really glad you're using CSS & not inline styling.

Comment: It a bit better because css files are more powerful than inline styles but `width90` is an anti pattern.  If the class was named something different like `.text-area` the width could be changed in one spot instead of many which is why inline should be avoided.

Comment: [Don't add classes for styles, add styles for classes](http://zzzzbov.com/blag/response-to-maintainablecss). Using a class like `width90` is a guaranteed way to end up with a [BBOM](http://www.laputan.org/mud/).

Comment: What about `normalize` that has classes like `text-left`, `text-center`, etc

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Looking at your updated question,

> Why is this

```
<div>
   <textarea class="width90"></textarea>
</div>

.width90{
   width:90%;
}
```

> any better than this?

```
<div>
   <textarea style="width:90%;"></textarea>
</div>
```

My answer is **It's not any better, and neither would pass a code review with me.**

As noted in the comments, if you wanted to change the width from 90% to 85%, you'd still have to make changes in many places.

It would be far better to give your `<textarea>` tag a semantically meaningful class name such as 'InvoiceDescription', 'container', 'col-md-1', and so on.  That way when someone later on wants to both change the width AND the font/background color/whatever, they can do it in one place.

Comment: I would go little further. If you need badly to set *style* attribute, do it programmatically via script. But avoid (if possible) to do it directly on the html.

Answer (score 8):

**In layman's terms:**

- Because when you have **a lot of pages** with **a lot of inline styling**, and **some user askes for cosmetics change**, the you will have to make a lot of changes in a lot of places, and chances are you will miss something.
- Having the css in the same file albeit in a separate `<STYLE>` section is almost as bad.
- With a separate css file you change the style in (hopefully) a single place and your site will have a coherent look.
- Then you can use the free time to pursue some hobby or learn to play a musical instrument.

Comment: I think you all miss the point. I have 1000 `<textareas>` with `style=width:90%"`. Mr Client wants them full width. What time am I saving by having to replace every related `style=width:90%"` with `style=width:100%"`, versus changing every `width90` class with `width100` class ?

Comment: The software axioms at play here are: "make decisions in one place" "Separate the things that change from the things that stay the same"

Comment: @BarryBones41 You missed the point. There's no point in having a `width90`or a `width100` class. You should have a `textarea` selector in a css file. It doesn't make sense calling the css class after one particular value.

Comment: That's exactly my point.... why would I create a class that just changes the width, instead of using inline? If I have 10 textareas and I don't want them all to be 90%, I cant just `.textarea{ width:90% }` and now you're saying don't use a class for the width.

Comment: The class should be named something like `.favoriteSongsTextArea`.  You may only have a single favorite song TextArea in the whole site, but who knows... in the future you might need a favorite song TextArea on multiple pages, and then you can just reuse the style.  Also, you may decide that favorite song TextArea needs a pink background... you can do that in the style and have it affect all instances.

Comment: @BarryBones41 You don't typically have 20 different text area sizes. In the interest of UI consistency you might have say, 3. Then you can create classes like textarea-sm, textarea-md, textarea-lg. If you're making classes like red-seventy-two-point-font-on-page-two you're eliminating the design advantages of CSS. The idea is to make general classes that apply to a number of elements so you can make changes across the application in one place.

Answer (score 0):

Just for fast manipulation of code the first format is used and the second format inline styling is going to extinct because inline styling makes the code look like chaos.

> **There is no difference in the outputs of the two formats, its just programmer's ease of code point of view.**